# Add cast to same type

Tags: java, casting

I've got an outer class `DoublyLinkedList<T>` and two inner classes `DoublyLinkedNode<T>` as well as `DoublyLinkedListIterator<T>`. They are arranged as follows:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> extends Collection<T> {

    private DoublyLinkedNode<T> head;
    private DoublyLinkedNode<T> tail;

    public class DoublyLinkedNode<T> {

        private DoublyLinkedNode<T> prev;
        private DoublyLinkedNode<T> next;
        T element;

    }

    public class DoublyLinkedListIterator<T> implements ListIterator<T> {

        private DoublyLinkedNode<T> current = head;

    }

}
```

Now since I heard / read on multiple pages in stackoverflow and other sources that an Iterator should be implemented in the corresponding iterable class like `DoublyLinkedList<T>`, I thought it would be easier since you have access to the outer classes fields. Now I want to initialize an instance of `DoublyLinkedListIterator<T>`, but Eclipse says at this point:

```
private DoublyLinkedNode<T> current = head;
```

inside the `DoublyLinkedListIterator<T>` that:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from DoublyLinkedList.DoublyLinkedNode< T > to DoublyLinkedList.DoublyLinkedNode< T >

And the only way to resolve this is by casting it with the same type again:

```
private DoublyLinkedNode<T> current = (DoublyLinkedNode<T>) head;
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Since `DoublyLinkedListIterator` implements `ListIterator`, it might by advisable to let `DoublyLinkedList` implement `List` on top of `Collection`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've declared inner classes `DoublyLinkedNode` and `DoublyLinkdListIterator`. 
 Inner classes have in scope all generic type parameters of the enclosing class, so `T` is already available to them.  When you declare them again, you are hiding the `T` on the enclosing class.  They are different `T`s.

Remove the re-declarations of `T` that are hiding the outer `T` (and your class should implement `Collection`, which is an interface), and let your inner classes use the outer `T`:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> implements Collection<T> {

    private DoublyLinkedNode head;
    private DoublyLinkedNode tail;

    public class DoublyLinkedNode {
        private DoublyLinkedNode prev;
        private DoublyLinkedNode next;
        T element;
    }

    public class DoublyLinkedListIterator implements ListIterator<T> {
        private DoublyLinkedNode current = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to deal with using `DoublyLinkedListIterator` outside of this class? Since the parameter type is now gone, a simple assignment like `DoublyLinkedListIterator iterator = someDoublyLinkedList.iterator();` only returns `Object` when calling the Iterators `next()` method. Adding a parameter to the type in the assignment does not work and adding a type parameter in the class declaration only reverts the changes you made.

Comment: When you return an instance of your iterator, have that method return the interface: `Iterator<T>` or `ListIterator<T>`.  Callers don't need to know your implementation.  You can even make `DoublyLinkedListIterator` `private`.